# SQL (Oracle) -How to Get Ratio from two Count Statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I want to get the Ratio of **count1 / count2** 
which gives me percent compliant.
this is right beneath my finger tips... 
Can I get some help?

```
Select 
 (
 Select Count (*) from tso_skf_nomeas_in60days_v 
 ) as count1, 
 (
 Select Count (*) from tso_skf_recent_meas
 ) as count2
 (
 from dual
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close:

```
Select 
    (Select Count (*) from tso_skf_nomeas_in60days_v) 
    / 
    (Select Count (*) from tso_skf_recent_meas) as perc
from dual
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fcbb9/2)

Comment: Awesome they have a SQL Fiddle like jsFiddle! Cool! Didn't know about that one.

Comment: @Ben_Coding -- gotta love the Fiddle :D  Hope we helped.  Best regards.

Comment: Not Working... Syntax issue I think. 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 44

Comment: @Ben_Coding -- Fiddle works -- perhaps missing something else?  Can you update the Fiddle and reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm gonna give you credit it works on SQL Fiddle.
Think I'll just have to try another machine or use SQL developer on another machine. How odd?

Comment: @Ben_Coding -- thanks, but I'd like it to work for you :) -- Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fcbb9/10 -- the above should work, but this is just another way of doing the same thing...

Comment: YEAH That did it!! I knew there had to be another way. It's just when you stare at it too long.

Comment: @Ben_Coding -- Great!!  Glad we could help.  Best regards!

Comment: You might like to modify the count in the denominator subquery to "case when count(*) = 0 then null else count(*) end" to avoid possible division by zero.

Comment: @David -Thanks David, that makes it more robust. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
(SELECT cast(COUNT(*) as float) FROM tso_skf_nomeas_in60days_v)
/
(SELECT cast(COUNT(*) as float) FROM tso_skf_recent_meas) as perc
FROM dual
```

Comment: Huh? It gives me 1110, I'm expecting something like 330/1110 = 0.297

Comment: if you run just the 2nd line and just the 4th line individually, what do you get?  Then if you run all 4 lines together, what do you get?

Comment: First Line = 320 
Select  (Select Count (*) from tso_skf_nomeas_in60days_v) 
from dual

Second Line = 1110
Select 
    (Select Count (*) from tso_skf_recent_meas) as perc
from dual;

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer by the way. I believe I'm on Oracle 10.2

Comment: ah - sorry, missed that it was Oracle. you just need a "from dual" at the end. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MikeMonteiro -- no need for the casting -- it will work fine without (unlike other rdbms).  Other than that, yes, you just needed the from dual...  Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

```
Select Count1/Count2
FROM (Select Count(*) Count1 From tso_skf_nomeas_in60days_v) tso_skf_nomeas_in60days_v,
(Select Count(*) Count2 From tso_skf_recent_meas) tso_skf_recent_meas;
```

as see on [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fcbb9/10)

Final Results:

[image]